# Etymology of “Fürst”

Tags: etymology

Is the word "Fürst" etymological/historical superlativ form of the word "vor"?

I believe they might be related, because of the umlaut and on account of the "st" on the end.

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrst

Comment: https://dwds.de/wb/F%C3%BCrst

Comment: @Carsten Sorry, but I do not understand(( Yes or no?

Comment: They are at least related. Of course, this is not supposed to be an answer. By the way, you could improve your answer by saying why you think that this might be the case.

Comment: @CarstenS because of the umlaut and on account of the "st" on the end

Comment: Fürst = first, Prinz = princeps

Comment: Just as a hint for the future: When wondering about etymology of a german word, there are two standard resources to resort to: Grimm and Pfeifer, both are available online: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GF12887#XGF12887 (Grimm) https://www.dwds.de/wb/Fürst (Pfeifer)

Answer (score 3):

According to Wiktionary, the word Fürst shares a common ancestor with the english word first, namely the proto-germanic word [furistaz](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/furistaz) (which means first or foremost). The word [vor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fora#Old_High_German) comes from the proto-germanic word [fora](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fora#Old_High_German).

Comment: Vor pretty much relates to *pre*, *für* and so on, for all I know, and thus to *first*? Compare *Prinz, princeps*. Will check.

Comment: What you say does not match the content of the links. *vor* "before" is deemed akin to "pre" indeed, and your second link agrees so far. PGMc \*w- remains *w-* in (all?) cases. *Lip* does not make too much sense here. The PIE root glossed *high* somewhat does make sense. But overall your argument is mildly irritating.

Comment: Please feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: I don't know what you were trying to say, so there's nothing for me to edit myself. What I said is something that can be looked up trivially in any etymological dictionary, and the maybe not so obvious tangent with *prince* is not an answer. I rather wonder how you arrived at PGmc \*weruz "lip" for a start. It's not obvious to me; whether right or wrong I may not judge, but even if wrong one could learn from mistakes.

Comment: Yeah I think I made a mistake there. Not sure how I arrived at weruz either.